# Save As File Dialog in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to show Save As File Dialog on click of a button in my html5 page. May I know how this can be achieved in Angular 6/Typescript?

Comment: Just use a normal HTML file input e.g. `<input type="file" />`

Comment: Thank you Kelvin. But it shows Open File Dialog not Save As. May I know how to show that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Create and save file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file)

Comment: What is the file you want to download? Is it is the web page itself or some other external file?

Comment: I want to get the path from the Save As file dialog and save as either an image file or zip file etc?

Comment: Kelvin: JavaScript: Create and save file : This looks like how to save a context to a given file name rather than showing a save as file dialog?

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that using ngx-filesaver 
this is **documentation** https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-filesaver
this is **Demo** https://cipchk.github.io/ngx-filesaver/

Comment: Thanks ! I checked the demo, it save the data in different file format with the file name save.txt etc but NOT showing Save As File dialog to get the path/file name from the user.

Comment: There is no Save As dialog there